# HyperGeometric distribution : Inutition for symmetry

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypergeometric-function

[Wikipedia page on HyperGeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) says

Swapping the roles of green and drawn marbles:

$$ f ( k ; N , K , n ) = f ( k ; N , n , K ) $$

where in LHS,

N = Total number of marbles

n = number of draws

K = number of green marbles(others are red)

k = number of green marbles in n draws

I understand how the equality holds mathematically, but I can't understand why this equality holds intuitively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider slightly different situations, both involving double selections:

- Suppose you have $N$ marbles of which you randomly select $K$ of the $N$ without replacement (to count as green), then put those back and independently select $n$ without replacement from your $N$ of which $K$ are green (to count as *drawn* in your hypergeometric distribution).  You have $f ( k ; N , K , n )$ as the probability mass function for the number $k$ which are selected both times
- Suppose you have $N$ marbles of which you randomly select $n$ of the $N$ without replacement (to count as green), then put those back and independently select $K$ without replacement from your $N$ of which $n$ are green (to count as *drawn* in your hypergeometric distribution).  You have $f ( k ; N , n , K )$ as the probability mass function for the number $k$ which are selected both times

It seems intuitively obvious to me that the probability of selecting $k$ marbles both times is the same in the each of these situations